# android: attribute is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

I have cloned project from github and opened it in android studio. I did it by downloading zip file and open project it in android studio. This cloned project is implemented on SDK version 23.

By doing this project build is successful but I am getting "android: attribute is not allowed here" error in manifest.xml file and main_activity.xml file for some attributes. This all attributes are working properly in other projects.

Here is the code for manifest.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.quakereport">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".EarthquakeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Here is the code for main_activity.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I am attaching image of both files.
[This is the image of manifest.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS0uS.png)
[This is the image of main_activity.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iKw.png)

I have tried..

1. close and reopen manifest.xml file
2. rebuild project
3. modify code on notepad and then put it in manifest.xml file.
4. confirmed that both files are at right place in hierarchy.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx">`  in your manifest.

Comment: show your full `main_activity.xml`

Comment: @m0skit0 Somehow I forgot to add those lines here but I already written those lines in my code. Now i attached images. I request you to review it.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya There is nothing other than comments in my main_activity.xml. Please review the image.